# Comparing 2 models with anova in R?

Tags: r, anova, interpretation, nested-models

I'm struggling to interpret this outcome.

I have 2 models

```
Model_1 <- lm(formula = gamble ~ income * gender)
Model_2 <- lm(formula = gamble ~ income + gender)
```

Now, I'm struggling to understand if these are nested and if so which one is full and which is reduced.

Then if i try to select a better one using `anova(Model_1, Model_2)` I get this output:

```
** Model 1: gamble ~ income * gender
Model 2: gamble ~ income + factor(gender)
  Res.Df   RSS Df Sum of Sq      F   Pr(>F)   
1     43 18930                                
2     44 22781 -1   -3851.4 8.7486 0.005018 **
```

It seems like the $p$ value is significant in favour of one of the models. Which one would that be?

Answer (score 0):

Model 2 is nested within Model 1, as setting the `income:gender` parameter in Model 1 equal to zero results in Model 2. Thus, Model 2 is the reduced model.

**Model 1**

$
\hat{y} = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 x_{income} + \hat{\beta}_2x_{gender} + \hat{\beta}_3 x_{income}x_{gender}
$

**Model 2**

$
\hat{y} = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 x_{income} + \hat{\beta}_2x_{gender}
$

What the `anova` function does is test if the parameters in the full model that are not in the reduced model are nonzero. You have a fairly small p-value, indicating that there is something nonzero in the full model that is not in the reduced model. Only $\beta_3$ is in the full model but not the reduced model.

Answer (score 0):

- Your models are nested. In the R formula language, `:` means interaction, while `*` means "expand into a sum plus the interaction". So the term `income * gender` expands into `income + gender + income:gender`, in effect including the possibility that slopes of income differs between genders, while the simpler model without the interaction assumes that slopes of<income are equal for genders, only the intercepts might differ (if income also is categorical, an analogous interpretation).
- The full model is the one with interaction `Model_1`, so the reduced model is `Model_2`.
- In your output you get negative df and negative SS. Thatb is because you had arguments to `anova` in the wrong order. The arguments should be in order of increasing complexity, so `anova(Model_2, Model_1)`
- The conclusion is that the full model (with interaction) is significant, as compared to the reduced model.